# Android how to display only some fields of a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to have one layout file with two text views and depending on a dynamic condition, I want to choose how many text fields to display. 
The attached code shows both the fields all the time :-(
The motivation behind such design is to avoid maintaining two activities and later divergence of look and feel.
Any help is appreciated.

The code to call text view creations, where m is decided as `0` or `1` based on other UI events. The goal is to display `m` number of text views:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        b = new B_ContactCollector(this, i);
        c.add(i, b);
    }
```

The code to create the text views

```
    switch (n) {
    case 0:
        tv = (TextView) f.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        b = (Button) f.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get a new Contact
                Intent i = new Intent (f, B_ContactLister.class);
                i.putExtra("windowNumber", 0);
                f.startActivityForResult(i,1);
            }
        }); 
        break;
    case 1: 
        tv = (TextView) f.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        b = (Button) f.findViewById(R.id.button2);  
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get a new Contact
                Intent i = new Intent (f, B_ContactLister.class);
                i.putExtra("windowNumber", 1);
                f.startActivityForResult(i,1);
            }
        }); 
        break;
    default:
        // throw an error that it shouldn't have come here  
        break;
    }
```

The layout is:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FF9D85"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv1"
    android:text="+" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#FF9D85"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv2"
    android:text="+" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/intro"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/intro" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put android:visibility="gone" or android:visibility="invisible" the item will be always visible.

One thing you can do is set the two pair of layouts (2x(Button+TextView)) and later change their visibility, like this:

```
tv = (TextView) f.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
b = (Button) f.findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // get a new Contact
        Intent i = new Intent (f, B_ContactLister.class);
        i.putExtra("windowNumber", 0);
        f.startActivityForResult(i,1);
   }
}); 

tv2 = (TextView) f.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
b2 = (Button) f.findViewById(R.id.button2);  
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // get a new Contact
        Intent i = new Intent (f, B_ContactLister.class);
        i.putExtra("windowNumber", 1);
        f.startActivityForResult(i,1);
     }
}); 

switch (n) {
    case 0:
        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 1: 
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        break;
    default:
        // throw an error that it shouldn't have come here  
        break;
}
```

Remember that if you put INVISIBLE the element wouldn't be shown but it will occupy space. Make the element GONE if you want both.

I'm not in front of the AndroidStudio/Eclipse, it might have fails, but this is what you should do.

Comment: Thanks. In my case as I wanted to display m number of windows and not m'th window, the code you suggested worked with slight modification. I will paste it my own question to add the code because the comment doesn't let me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marc. The modified code to solve the problem as I stated is:

```
    tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    switch (n) {
    case 0:
        tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        b2.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
        break;
    case 1: 
        tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    default:
        // throw an error that it shouldn't have come here  
        break;
    }
```

Comment: You're welcome, but please check the question as answered, thanks.